# retrieve records based on 2 columns conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a question about SQL Server.

```
Table : location

  Id  | status  | locid
  ----+---------+-------
  1   | D       |10
  2   | D       |
  3   | C       |20
  4   | A       |
  5   | D       |
  6   | F       |
  7   |         |20
  8   |         |
```

Here, based on condition if `locid is empty or null and status !='d'` then we need to retrieve that record.

Based on above table I want output like this:

```
Id  |  status   | locid
----+-----------+-------

 4   |  A        |
 6   |  F        |
 8   |           |
```

I tried this query:

```
select * 
from location 
where  status!= 'D' and locid='' or locid is null
```

but it's not returning the expected results. Please tell me how to write a query to achive this task in SQL Server.

Comment: Just use parentheses so the conditions are evaluated the way you intend them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select * 
from location
where  status <> 'D' and isnull(locid,'')=''
```